# DialogFragment is not dismissed in live for some scenario

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, appcompatdialogfragment

I am using a `AppCompatDialogFragment`. My dialogFragment is not dismissed in some scenario.

The scenario flow is

1. Showing the dialogFragment
2. dialogFragment UI has a Button.In button click a api is called and after api response i dismiss the dialog and set an myObject to null as i don't need that object.
3. Then i show second dialog and user manually dismiss this dialog
4. After dismissing second dialog users are able to interact(click on that button) with first dialogFragment

I am getting a crash on dialogFragment button click for null object reference on myObject which i previously set to null.

User is able to click button after dialogFragment dismiss call. As i have set myObject to null first time so i'm getting Exception.But user shouldn't able to click second time as i have called dismiss().

I can't generate this Exception and its happening in live in some cases and i have traced the scenario with Crash Log

> Crash happens only when user are able to click second time

Why the dialogFragment is not dismissing some case? I am using `dialogFragment.dismiss()` method for dismiss.

Is this happening for state loss issue? But i think for state loss issue i should get a Exception for `IllegalStateException`

A workaround may be `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` .

Any one can explain the scenario ? why this happening or how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: Actually only responsible code is `dialogFragment.show()` and `dialogFragment.dismiss()`